# Xamarin.iOS: can't put image into UIImageView

Tags: uiimageview, xamarin.ios

I dragged and dropped a UIViewImage into my ViewController. I've the put the image in the references folder. Then in the ImageView's properties, under widget tab, in the image field, I click the blue down arrow button and the browse window opens. I selected the image and clicked open. But it does not show. This is all I've used to do in Xcode.

Also after I selected the image, the name of the image is not showing in Widget > Image View > Image

I'm using Xamarin Studio on mac. Why does it not work? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to do it using the story board but if you want to simply code it in, you can use this block of code in your view controller. Make sure the file is a bundle resource in your Resources folder.

```
var img = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("img.jpg"));
img.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height);
View.AddSubview(img);
```

The frame you can set to whatever size you would like.